# Protocol for remote serial port, with authentication and encryption

Tags: serial-port, network-protocols, remote-access

I'd like to make a serial port available over the network. [RFC-2217](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2217) provides extensions to Telnet to transport extra serial port info such as speed, data bits, stop bits, and hardware handshaking lines.

However, I want to ensure it's not freely accessible to just anyone on the network, so I want to do authentication and encryption. Telnet is weak on authentication and does not provide encryption. SSH is generally preferred over Telnet.

Is there any protocol that allows serial port transport through SSH, similar to [RFC-2217](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2217)?

I realise one option could be to tunnel Telnet + [RFC-2217](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2217) through an SSH tunnel. That is technically achievable, though in practical terms it's a little awkward.

**Zeroconf**

The other question is, how could such a port be advertised with Zeroconf DNS-SD? E.g. how could a Telnet + RFC-2217 serial port, that is tunnelled through SSH, be advertised with Zeroconf? (plain Telnet + RFC-2217 might be advertised as `_telnetcpcd._tcp` from what I can tell.)

Comment: Any reason not to just run PuTTY on both ends?  http://superuser.com/questions/270793/connect-two-computers-together-via-a-rs232-serial-port

Comment: It's for a niche radio communications application, and I want to enable PCs to connect to the radio modem over a local network, for dial-up access. The client PC would then use a virtual serial port, and the usual AT commands to dial a data call.

Comment: RFC2217 over SSH, as you have proposed, sounds like the perfect solution to me.  I'm not sure what's awkward about it... seems like a good fit.

Comment: @Brad, if I understand correctly, RFC-2217 works with Telnet, but not with SSH. Correct me if I'm wrong. So the option that could work is SSH tunneling of another protocol (Telnet + RFC-2217). SSH tunneling would work, but is more complicated to set up on the client (first use SSH to open the tunnel, then use a Telnet + RFC-2217 driver to connect to the tunnel's port on `localhost`).

Comment: SSH tunneling is what I would suggest.  Seems like it would actually be easiest.

Comment: I had a bounty on this question, but didn't get around to awarding it. My excuse is that my wife had a baby the day the bounty expired. (I think it's a good excuse!) Once I've had a chance to think I'll figure out if I should do something further to be fair to those who answered.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen Congratulations!  I can only speak for myself, but definitely don't worry about letting the bounty expire un-awarded on my behalf.  I just hope the new kid's happy and healthy and that you sort out a good way to do this odd authenticated serial over the network business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a secured serial-over-LAN connection.

The reason why you don't find any free project which does this is simple – most open source projects seperate the transport layer security from the protocol (for good reasons). Instead of re-inventing the wheel for every application, you can just re-use the security component (SSH in this case) and apply it to your unsecured protocol (RFC-2217-compatible, for example).

Just use a SSH tunnel or *stunnel* to secure the connection. For Windows clients, you can use *com2com* and for *nix systems something like *ttyd*.

*com2com*, for example, does not even requires to be started manually after initial setup, so your users only have to establish a SSH tunnel (through PuTTY, for example).

- [com2com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/)
- [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/), using `pty` and `openssl-listen` you can do pretty much exactly what you want (slightly contradicts what I wrote above because it actually *does* implement transport layer security)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that SSH tunneling is as awkward as you think:

> **-W** *host*:port
>   Requests that standard input and output on the client be forwarded to host on port over the secure channel.  Implies **-N**, **-T**, **ExitOnForwardFailure** and **ClearAllForwardings** and works with Protocol version 2 only.

Here's what tunneling a short SMTP session looks like (typed input in bold):

```
$ ssh -W mail.server.com:25 blahdiblah@server.com
220 mail.server.com ESMTP 
Postfix
ehlo foo.com
250-mail.server.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE
250-ETRN
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

No separate setting up a tunnel and then connecting to that port, just piping input and output from the ssh process.

Answer (score 0):

SSH provides for ["requesting a pseudo-terminal"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#section-6.2) with ["pseudo-terminal encoded terminal modes"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#section-8). It provides for setting baud rate, bits, parity, stop bits configuration. It's possible to set `PARMRK` to receive framing errors and break condition. However, it seems the SSH protocol currently lacks any commands to *set* a break condition, or to set DTR and RTS modem hardware lines, or to get DSR, CTS, DCD and RING modem hardware lines.

See:

- [RFC 4254 - The Secure Shell (SSH) Connection Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254)
- [Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol Parameters — IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ssh-parameters/ssh-parameters.xhtml)